# Regex for matching more than one dot in any part of string (consecutive and not consecutive)

Tags: java, regex

I need a regular expression for a string containing more than one dot.

For example, correct:

```
12345..01100033
12345.0110.0033
12345.0110.003........3
```

Not correct:

```
123450110.0033
1234501100033
```

The string can also contain letters.
I can only create a regular expression for one dot:

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9,]*[.]{1}[a-zA-Z0-9,]*$
```

How can I create regex for two or more dots that can appear in any part of string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah, this works!

```
public class RegexTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(".*\\..*\\..*");
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("12345.0110.0033");
        if (matcher.find()) {
            System.out.println("found");
        }
    }
}
```